# Polygon to Raster conversion: Raster shifted ~10m horizontally. How to fix?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, rasterization, vectorization

I converted a number of polygons into a raster. The cell size is correct but the raster has shifted ~10m horizontally.

Is there an issue with my method or is there a tool I can use to fix this?

Comment: Check out snap raster environment parameter.

Comment: Sounds like a snap raster issue as @fatih_dur suggests. That would be the best option, but you can also shift rasters with the unsurprisingly named shift tool in ArcMap. So read the help file on snap raster settings or shift tool.